# creating directories in less than 3 commands

Tags: linux, directory

I can only use 3 commands to make 8 directories and a answer file.I used the first command to create a answer file. The second command I used to create 2 of the directories. I've run out of commands to use and still have to do 6 directories. Is there a specific command that allows you to create multiple directories in one step.

Comment: You question is vague.

What is an answer file? Why 8 directories? Why 3 commands?

I suggest you to spend more time on composing your question than people posting answers to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes mkdir:

```
mkdir dira dirb dirc dird
```

Creates four directories `dira`, `dirb`, `dirc`, and `dird`.

In one go:

```
mkdir dir{a..d}
```

Comment: And `mkdir -p a/b/c` to shorten `mkdir a a/b a/b/c` (and avoid the errors when the directories already exist).

Comment: Don’t we have a ‘‘Please don’t feed the bears.’’ policy?   We probably should.

Comment: @G-Man Would you like to explain your comment, Thanks.

Comment: You are doing other people's university coursework for them.  https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4206/  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401294/

Comment: … and, by doing so, encouraging them to bring their homework problems to us as a first resort (rather than as a last resort) in the future. Just as feeding wild animals teaches them that people are a good source of food, which can only lead to trouble.

Comment: To be fair, this Question at least came close to asking an answerable question (about creating multiple directories at once); it would take clicking on the OP’s profile to see their previous question(s), the most recent of which was similar and closed.

Comment: Yeah, but arbitrary restrictions like “I can only use three commands” are atypical of real life,  and so are a red flag.