# Add a different string in the beginning of each line

Tags: text-processing, awk

So I have a txt with some numbers inside and I want to add a string before those numbers, but not the same string in every line. So for example I have:

```
49.950
38.654
104.138
168.171
100.586
```

and I want to add before them the words nick, george, james so the result will be

```
www.abc.com 49.950
www.facebook.com 38.654
www.youtube.com 104.138
www.google.com 168.171
www.twitch.com 100.586
```

How am I gonna do that?

```
while read -r line; do x="$line"
 if [ "$line" == "www.abc.com" ]; then
  ping -c 4 www.abc.com | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2 > results
 fi
 if [ "$line" == "www.facebook.com" ]; then
  ping -c 4 www.facebook.com | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2 >> results 
 fi
 if [ "$line" == "www.youtube.com" ]; then
  ping -c 4 www.youtube.com | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2 >> results
 fi
 if [ "$line" == "www.google.com" ]; then
  ping -c 4 www.google.com | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2 >> results
 fi
 if [ "$line" == "www.twich.com" ]; then
  ping -c 4 www.twitch.com | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2 >>results
 fi
done <urls
```

Comment: what if there would be more that 3 numbers?

Comment: I have a fixed amount of numbers, they are 5. Actually i'm reading from a txt of 5 urls and I ping every url 4 times, i take the average time of each url and add it to a new txt. So i'm having 5 lines of the 5 average times and i just need to add in front of them the equivalent urls.

Comment: update your question with those 5 numbers and respective names/URLs. Also, it's good to post your current code

Comment: So, you just want merge two files, line by line? Then, `paste -d' ' first.txt second.txt` would be enough.

Comment: The result you wrote doesn't match the description right before it. You mention names that do not appear on the example output.

Comment: @Georgio3, ok, post that file with 5 urls

Comment: it's just 5 urls. i posted the code. Why is it displaying that way?

Comment: Because you didn't format the block of code using the `{}` _format code_ button on the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete **`bash`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
while read -r url || [ -n "$url" ]; do 
    ping -c4 "$url" | awk -F'/' -v u="$url" 'END{ print u,$5 }'
done <urls > results
```

---

The exemplary `results` file contents (as a result of my local test):

```
www.abc.com 207.137
www.facebook.com 39.938
www.youtube.com 35.580
www.google.com 128.124
www.twitch.com 144.557
```

Comment: This is a complete solution, describes the whole process? From pinging to generating the final txt file?

Comment: @Georgio3, you may try and see. The only nuance is that this will ping all the input urls

Comment: Thank god, finally! It's just a bonus project in my OS class. I'm striving for 2 days to complete it. I'm not going to continue learning Bash, that's for sure

Comment: @Georgio3, you're welcome. As for leaning - **bash** is pretty useful for System/Unix programming. Anyway, it's your choice

Comment: I really don't like Linux, I prefer Windows and my plans are to become a Java Software Developer, so I don't think i'll need it and since i don't like it there's no reason to learn it. Thanks again

Comment: Java is primarily used these days to develop server software and the vast majority of such software runs on Linux. As a 20-year veteran of primarily Java software development I can tell you that you that there is a very high probability you will need at some familiarity with Linux command line tools, scripting and general systems knowledge (unless you are referring to developing Java desktop applications...a shrinking, niche market if ever there was one).

Comment: This won't take the last line if it doesn't end with a linebreak. Use `while read -r url || [ -n "$url" ]; do …; done <urls` instead to be sure.

Comment: You could also just redirect the whole loop's output instead of opening the file multiple times inside the loop: `…; done <urls >results`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest `while read -r url; do echo $url; done <urls` echos *all five* urls for you even if the file doesn't end with an empty line? That's odd, it doesn't do that for me with `GNU bash, Version 4.3.48`.

Comment: Please note that [we have a policy not to do people’s homework for them](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4206/80216).   I realize that it was not 100% obvious that this was homework (until the OP said so), and the question did demonstrate an effort to solve the problem, but please be alert to questions that are too formulaic (like [this one](https://superuser.com/q/1269744/354511)) or artificial (like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401272/80216)) and Vote to Close them.   Please do not answer them.

Comment: As a side note, if something this straightforward was a “bonus project”, I wonder how simple the main, mandatory homework is! … … … … … … … … … … … … … … P.S. dessert is right on both counts. The shell’s `read` builtin fails if it reads a line that doesn’t end with a newline, and you could say `> results` on the `done` line rather than `>> results` on the `ping … |  awk …` command.

Comment: I have tested (and verified) it with bash version 4.1.17.  Perhaps you have a different version.

Comment: @G-Man, ok, updated

Comment: @dessert, ok, updated